# Telethon event.reply() does not send any message, expected to get a reply from a Telegram bot

Tags: python, telethon

Telegram bot does not reply anything. Any reason?

```
async def main(): 
    async with TelegramClient('new_session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        @client.on(events.NewMessage)
        async def my_event_handler(event):
            await event.reply('Message is received')
nest_asyncio.apply()
asyncio.run(main())
```

Expected to receive 'Message is received' from a Telegram bot

Comment: What is `nest_asyncio`? Does the script print anything at all? Are there logs?

Comment: usually bots need to run `"event loop"` which runs all time and it checks if there is message from user. So usually code has `client.loop.run_until_complete(main())` or `client.loop.run_forever()`. Without running `"event loop"` your code may simply finish running before it can get any message from user and it can't send response.

Answer (score 0):

Bot need to run `"event loop"` which runs all time and it checks if there is some event (like message from user) and it executes functions assigned to this event.

Usually code has `client.loop.run_until_complete(main())` or `client.loop.run_forever()` or `client.run_until_disconnected()` to run this loop.

Without running "event loop" your code simply finish running before it can get any message from user and it can't send response.

---

Minimal working code which shows were to use `client.run_until_disconnected()`

```
import asyncio
import os
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

API_ID   = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_API_ID')
API_HASH = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_API_HASH')

async def main(): 
    async with TelegramClient('new_session', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:

        @client.on(events.NewMessage)
        async def my_event_handler(event):
            await event.reply('Message is received')

        print('Starting event loop')
        await client.run_until_disconnected()  # <-- you need this

asyncio.run(main())
```

---

**BTW:** If you run bot in some other code which uses `async` and it needs other `event loop` then it may need to create own loop ( instead of `client.run_until_disconnected()`) which will run code from two different `event loops` at the same time. But this can be more complex problem and it needs other details about full code.

Comment: Thank you! To make your code work I had to add `nest_asyncio.apply()` before `asyncio.run(main())`. After that the problem was resolved.